# Eliminate Haskell array bounds check for Bounded type?

Tags: arrays, haskell, ghc, bounds-check-elimination

I am making a good many arrays whose index type is `Bounded` and whose index range is `(minBound, maxBound)`.  For such an array, a bounds check ought to be unnecessary.  How can I persuade GHC to eliminate the bounds check?

My particular application uses both boxed and unboxed immutable arrays, but I am interested in all types of Haskell arrays.

Comment: Well, what array type is it?  Is it just `Data.Array.IArray`?

Answer (score 14):

Import `Data.Array.Base`, compute the `Int` index of the desired element, and use

```
someArray `unsafeAt` computedIndex
```

to avoid the range-check (`unsafeRead` and `unsafeWrite` for mutable arrays). The computation of the `Int` index without range check *should* be available via `unsafeIndex` from the `Ix` class if you `import GHC.Arr`.

If the `Ix` instance of your index type doesn't provide a fast unchecked `unsafeIndex` function, you have to write it yourself. That may be preferable anyway since your range `(minBound, maxBound)` is constant and needn't be passed to the index computation.